# MVC disable EditFor() based on value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC 4

I have in my *.ascx page the following to display a textbox on a page:

```
<div class="editor-field inner">
       <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Number) %>
</div>
```

my model has a `bool` property `allowEdit` that indicates if the user should be allowed to edit a certain piece of information. When the value is false, I want to still show the textbox but disable it.

I've tried using jquery as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myModel = '<%=Model.allowEdit%>';

        if(myModel == false)
        {
            alert("HELLO");
        }
        });
</script>
```

How can i dynamically enable/disable certain textboxes based on model value?

Comment: Is the alert not firing?

Comment: Try using `myModel === 'false'`. `'false' == false` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Also could you show the view the html that the EditorFor is injecting in.

Comment: sorry, the alert("HELLO"); was left in for testing and I was not able to see it either... I will try @Erik's answer and see how it goes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me say that you need to do validation not just on the client, but on the server as well.  Since a client could bypass the javascript, or submit values manually to bypass it.

Having said that, if you're using MVC5.1 or greater, you can simply do this:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Number, new { htmlAttributes = 
   Model.allowEdit ? (object)new {} : new { disabled = "disabled" }}) %>
```

Also, be aware that disabled controls do not post their values back to the server, so make sure that your post handler isn't expecting the value.  You could replace disabled with readonly above to use the readonly attribute instead.

EDIT:

If you can't use MVC5.1 or later, then you have two choices.  Either create a custom EditorTemplate, which is probably more work than it's worth for this.  Or just use TextBoxFor instead.  You would change the syntax slightly to this:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Number, 
        Model.allowEdit ? (object)new {} : new { disabled = "disabled" }) %>
```

Comment: Given that disabled controls do not post their values back, if that is something that one needs, use the readonly property on the control.  This prevents changing the value but still allows the value to POST back (and be copied from the text box)  http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: Pretty sure this won't work. I believe setting `disabled`to an empty string also makes the input disabled. Edit: in fact, whatever value you give it, as long as the attribute is present, the input ends up disabled.

Comment: @Dom As of razor2, that should not render if it's empty.

Comment: @Erik You're right, actually. Didn't notice you used `EditorFor`. I guess it should be noted that `TextBoxFor` will actually render empty attributes though.

Comment: @Dom - no, looks like you're right.. Razor2+ will only not render if it's actually in the html not if it's in a helper.  I'll update.

Comment: FWIW, you can just do: `htmlAttributes = new { disabled = Model.allowEdit }`. Razor is smart enough to either render the `disabled` attribute or not based on the boolean. Also, the condition of MVC 5.1 or above is only applicable to passing `htmlAttributes` with `EditorFor`. If you switch to a helper other than `EditorFor`, like `CheckboxFor`, the code will work with any version of MVC.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - Unfortunately, that's not true.  This does in fact render `disabled="false"` but the browser views anything in this tag as being true even false... so this results in a disabled form element.  The disabled attribute must not be present at all for it to not be disabled.  If we were manually rendering an input tag, and used `disabled="@..."` then Razor would be smart enough, but it doesn't know how to do this in helpers.  I made the same mistake as you initially.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: What do you know. I could've sworn I've successfully done this before, but just confirmed that you're correct. Perhaps, the behavior changed at some point.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - Inorite???  Lol.  Two High rep users getting it wrong on the same simple thing, must be a full moon or something.

Comment: Hey, I'll be the first to admit I'm quite often wrong. I've got too many years of too many different languages and versions thereof to keep everything straight. If it wasn't for Intellisense, I'd be curled up in the fetal position on the floor ;).

Comment: I'm using MVC4 and can't upgrade at the moment; what's my alternative? I've tried the suggestions above but nothing seems to work...

Comment: @fifamaniac04 - ok, do you have to use EditorFor then?  Can you just use TextBoxFor?

Comment: I don't believe there are restrictions on needing to use the EditorFor... What do I need to do if I use TextBoxFor() ?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Thanks for the help; that was what I was looking for!  If i wanted to do similar things with other controls, (ie DropDownListFor) would I just apply the same idea? What are these methods called so I can look them up more?

Comment: @fifamaniac04 - Helper methods have several overloads, you need to make sure to select the correct one.  Typically you are using the overload that has a parameter called htmlAttributes, which is a dictionary of key/value pairs that are translated to their equivalent HTML attributes.  Here we are using C# anonymous objects to map to this dictionary as a convenient shorthand.